# Automatically create and publish multiple apps from one Flutter code base

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, fastlane

Is it possible to automatically run a script that exchanges the configuration file, splash screen, app icons, and name and then automatically publishes it in the Google Play Store or App Store from the same Flutter code base? In addition to the configuration file, a new Firebase project must probably be created automatically, since the bundle identifier changes and I then need different Firebase configuration files for the push notifications, right? Does anyone have an idea how to implement something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the work could be accomplished with `flavors`.  I know [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash) and [https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons] both support flavors.